# how to extent this code to accommodate D and E drives as well

Tags: extent

I would like to extent the following code to accommodate all other drives on my machine.
Below code was written only on C drive..i am having difficulty modifying it, tried seperating values for driveletters, but the code is not displaying anything when run..

```
$ServerListFile = "D:\serverList.txt"  
$ServerList = Get-Content $ServerListFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
$Result = @() 
ForEach($c`enter code here`omputername in $ServerList) 
{

$AVGProc = Get-WmiObject -computername $computername win32_processor | 
Measure-Object -property LoadPercentage -Average | Select Average
$OS = gwmi -Class win32_operatingsystem -computername $computername |
Select-Object @{Name = "MemoryUsage"; Expression = {“{0:N2}” -f ((($_.TotalVisibleMemorySize - 
$_.FreePhysicalMemory)*100)/ $_.TotalVisibleMemorySize) }}
$vol = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_Volume -ComputerName $computername -Filter "DriveLetter = 'C:'" |
Select-object @{Name = "C PercentFree"; Expression = {“{0:N2}” -f  (($_.FreeSpace / $_.Capacity)*100) 
} }

$result += [PSCustomObject] @{ 
ServerName = "$computername"
CPULoad = "$($AVGProc.Average)%"
MemLoad = "$($OS.MemoryUsage)%"
CDrive = "$($vol.'C PercentFree')%"
}
$Outputreport = "<HTML><TITLE> Server Health Report </TITLE>
             <BODY background-color:peachpuff>
             <font color =""#99000"" face=""Microsoft Tai le"">
             <H2> Server Health Report </H2></font>
             <Table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
             <TR bgcolor=gray align=center>
               <TD><B>Server Name</B></TD>
               <TD><B>Avrg.CPU Utilization</B></TD>
               <TD><B>Memory Utilization</B></TD>
               <TD><B>Drive C Free Space</B></TD>
               </TR>"
 
   Foreach($Entry in $Result) 

  { 
  if(($Entry.CpuLoad) -or ($Entry.memload) -ge "80") 
  { 
    $Outputreport += "<TR bgcolor=white>" 
  } 
  else
   {
    $Outputreport += "<TR>" 
  }
  $Outputreport += "<TD>$($Entry.Servername)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.CPULoad)</TD><TD 
  align=center>$($Entry.MemLoad)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.CDrive)</TD></TR>" 
   }
   $Outputreport += "</Table></BODY></HTML>" 
   } 

   $Outputreport | out-file "D:\Result $(Get-Date -Format yyy-mm-dd-hhmm).htm"
```